# How to simulate cookie domain in browser

Tags: debugging, cookies, localhost

I'm currently developing/testing a webapp in Node.js and ExpressJS.
The server is running on `localhost:3000`, and in the code the cookie domain is set to `.webappname.com`

Whenever I'm trying to access cookie data within the browser, it fetches the cookie for `localhost`.

**How can I make it fetch the cookie for the set domain?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hosts file to map .webappname.com requests to localhost:

- Windows

  - Open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add the following:

    ```
    127.0.0.1       .webappname.com
    ```
- Linux

  - Open `/etc/hosts` and add the following:

    ```
    127.0.0.1       .webappname.com
    ```

**References**

- [App Transport Security and local networking | Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6205#72351)
- [How can I reset the Hosts file back to the default?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/972034)
- [Control the Emulator from the Command Line: Configuring the emulator DNS settings | Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#dns)